# SQL Server Provider?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to solve this Error

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   OLE DB provider
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be
>   used for distributed queries because
>   the provider is configured to run in
>   single-threaded apartment mode.

Comment: Hi jay, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, from the description you've provided, there's not really enough information to diagnose your problem. You'll have to be a little more specific and tell us what you were trying to do when that error occurred, as well as any other information you might think is relevant.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And is it 64 bit (SQL Server and OS)?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 64 bit , windows 7 

i export sql server data to excel

Answer (score 1):

I just did a bit of research on this myself. Here's the MSDN article that describes the error and provides a basic resolution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645919.aspx

Information on what single threaded and multi threaded apartments are:

[Single-Threaded Apartments vs Multi-Threaded Apartments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485086/single-threaded-apartments-vs-multi-threaded-apartments)

This was a page where someone had the problem and a number of possible solutions were posted:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=119887

From the research i've just done, you might be trying to connect to a linked server that may be running Oracle. You'll need to use a different provider to connect to it. That's based on what you've provided, and what i've found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using an Access database and you're trying to run a query that joins between that Access database and a server based system like SQL or Oracle. Thing is that won't work (you've seen the error message). For a database to be able to handle queries across two or more separate systems it needs to support some kind of distributed transaction support and that's not Access.

I think the best solution for this is to move the data from Access into SQL or vice versa.