# OLE DB provider 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' cannot be used for distributed queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle, oledb

Getting Following error while trying to executing  Oracle SP in ASP.NET.Here there is no Linked server concept. I am directly connecting to Oracle using Oracle connection.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: OLE DB provider 'OraOLEDB.Oracle'
>   cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is
>   configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable)

Comment: [Distributed transaction error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999906/distributed-transaction-error) and  [Unable to begin a distributed transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction)

Answer (score 2):

'OraOLEDB.Oracle' is a generic implementation to connect to various databases from MS technology. It is  STA (Single threaded Apartment) implementation in COM, so when internally your code tries to spawn another thread for a distributed query it throws an exception, since STA is not a thread safe implementation. The .Net processes are MTA (Multi threaded Apartment), which means they can handle the multiple threads in one go. Check these links for more information:

[Could you explain STA and MTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta)

[Single-Threaded Apartments vs Multi-Threaded Apartments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485086/single-threaded-apartments-vs-multi-threaded-apartments)

Best option for you would be to shift to [ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), which is a pure .Net product and will not have such issues. It has inbuilt support for distributed queries / transactions supported by Oracle. In fact you would be using ORAMTS for the purpose, which is Oracle's hook for the MSDTC (MS distributed transaction co-ordinator)