# WPF form in Visual Studio Add-in Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-addins, vs-extensibility

I am building a visual Studio 2008 add-in. That Add-in needs a UI for user inputs. I was planning to use WPF for that UI. But i am not able to find a way to make that working.
Is there any way to have a WPF form in Visual-studio add-in project?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? How did you try to do it?

Comment: I added the reference to PresentationCore and PresentationFramework. Removed the Reference to Systems.Windows.forms so that Window class now belongs to WPF framework rather than the winforms. 
But once i trying to launch this WPF form,the Add-in crashes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it crashes because WPF is MTA and Addins are STA.
[MTA vs STA more explanation available here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta)

Try with winforms to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to use WPF UIs in an Addin? And is that still the case in Visual Studio 2010? (and 2012?)