# STAThread and Process output capture in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

This is a strange problem I encountered. I have an window application written in c# to do testing. It has a MDI parent form that is hosting a few children forms. One of the forms launch test scripts by creating processes and capture the scripts output to a text box. Another form open serial port and monitoring the status of the device I am working on(like a shell). If I ran both of them together, the output of the script seems only appear in the text box after the test is done. However, If I don't open the serial port form, the output of the script is captured in real time.

Does anyone knows what's causing the problem? I notice the onDataReceived evenT handler for serial port form has a [STAThread] header to it. Will this cause the serial port thread having higher priority than other processes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SAT?  cripts?  [SAThread]?  Please edit your post to make your question legible.

Answer (score 1):

STATHREAD is required for a UI thread. From MSDN:

> Indicates that the COM threading model for an application is single-threaded apartment (STA).

Also, a windows form application will only have a single UI thread. It sounds like what you may need to do to have a responsive UI is use a background worker thread to control running your script, and have it communicate changes back to the UI thread.

Comment: +1 It does sound like the problem is the UI thread being blocked.

Comment: I used delegate function approach to update UI in my window form. It worked find until I ran them with the serial port form. Is there a way to see what's going on using debugger provided by visual studio?
I want to see why the UI thread is blocked if serial port form is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any case where the `[STAThread]` attribute will cause the thread to have higher priority.

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta) that discusses the differences between STA and MTA threads:

> The COM threading model is called an
>   "apartment" model, where the execution
>   context of initialized COM objects is
>   associated with either a single thread
>   (Single Thread Apartment) or many
>   threads (Multi Thread Apartment). In
>   this model, a COM object, once
>   initialized in an apartment, is part
>   of that apartment for the duration of
>   it's runtime.
>
> The STA model is used for COM objects
>   that are not thread safe. That means
>   they do not handle their own
>   synchronization. A common use of this
>   is a UI component. So if another
>   thread needs to interact with the
>   object (such as pushing a button in a
>   form) then the message is marshalled
>   onto the STA thread. The windows forms
>   message pumping system is an example
>   of this.
>
> If the COM object can handle its own
>   synchronization then the MTA model can
>   be used where multiple threads are
>   allowed to interact with the object
>   without marshalled calls.