# STA thread in windowapplication

Tags: c#, winforms, sta

I have a bit of code in my project like shown below,here what is the usage of STA thread ?
What i know about STA is it is Single Threaded Apartment,it is only required when using COM components.And it is used in the main entry of the application.

```
/// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// 
        /// Command line:
        ///   Leaf.exe /s server-name
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.DoEvents();
                Application.Run(new Leaf()); // Leaf is a constructor

        }
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN answers your questions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx)

It has no effect on other functions. It only has effect if your program uses COM interop.