# When should I set a thread to ApartmentState.STA?

Tags: c#, .net

I am curious to know when STA/MTA are used in C# .net?

```
using (ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim(false)) 
{       
    Thread _STAThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>                 
        {
             globalComObject = new ComClass();                     
             mre.Set();                     
             try                     
             {                         
                  Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
             }
             catch (ThreadAbortException)                     
             { } 
         }));
     _STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);                    
     _STAThread.IsBackground = true;                 
     _STAThread.Start();                 
     mre.Wait(); 
}
```

Comment: **See also**:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use them when doing interop with STA/MTA COM objects.

Answer (score 5):

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta) would give you a plenty.
Read also [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/260741-difference-between-sta-mta) and [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate.aspx).
The gist of it is that STA apartment is used for non thread-safe COM objects, while MTA can be used thread-safe COM objects in a multi-threaded fashion.