# Is there a performance cost for passing a com object to a BackgroundWorker and then accessing it?

Tags: c#, .net, com

Background: I've got a form that calls a background worker to do some intense computation.  I'm COM objects into an object array, and passing it to the background worker, where I unpack them and work with it.  ILayer is a com object.

The code looks something like this.

```
private void run()
{
    ESRI.Geodatabase.ILayer layer1 = getLayer();
    ESRI.Geodatabase.ILayer layer2 = getLayer2();

    object[] args = {(object)layer1, (object)layer2};

    BackgroundWorker1.runAsynchronous(args);

}

private void backgroundworker_dowork(object sender, events e)
{
    object[] args = (object[])e.Argument;
    ESRI.Geodatabase.ILayer layer1 = (ILayer)args[0];
    ESRI.Geodatabase.ILayer layer2 = (ILayer)args[1];
    services.doIntensiveOperations(layer1, layer2);

}
```

My question is this: is there a performance cost to making repeated calls to ILayer and/or its members from the background worker?  What is actually happening in memory here?

Comment: There is a performance cost for every action imaginable, whether or not its big enough to affect the acceptable time is a different matter

Comment: There may be a significant performance cost if you're using a very old machine with lack of resources (RAM, CPU, etc.) but if your target environment has enough of them then you should no worry about it. However when you're thinging about the performance cost you must first define some benchmark and limitations and check if your execution fits in the limitations and is acceptable compared to the benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

**Typically** COM objects have thread affinity, though in your case you'd have to take a look at the implementation of `ILayer` to find out its affinity and apartment thread model. If your objects have thread affinity, every time you make a call to `ILayer` the marshaller will dispatch a call to the owning thread of your `ILayer`. This means if you call the layer objects frequently, you'll have a very chatty communication between your background thread and the thread that owns the COM object and that could lead to performance slower than you'd want.

My answer above is not really precise because COM objects have a world of their own, at least in my opinion. Do some research on apartments, STA and MTA to get more information.

I just googled and look [what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643652/accessing-com-object-from-thread-other-than-main-thread-slow-in-c-sharp) I stumbled upon. The answer from Hans probably answers your question more precisely.