# background worker thread issue in windows form application

Tags: c#-4.0

Im exporting a reports from dataset to a execel file,i have a lots of reports so it consuming me a lots of time,so I try to solve this by the background worker cuz I'm working on windows form application,but the new issue come,when begin excuting  the report my form is not responding,I'm not able to move the form or click on the stop button(that stop the application).

this is a sample of my code :

```
#region x Report 

PrimaryReportsThreads++;
ADIR_Parameters ADIR_Parms = ConfigManager.GetADIRParameters();
BackgroundWorker ADIR_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
AllThreads.Add(ADIR_worker);
ADIR_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ADIR_worker_DoWork);
ADIR_worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
ADIR_worker.RunWorkerAsync(ADIR_Parms);

#endregion
```

Comment: Don't call ReportProgress too often.

Comment: can you be clear more please hans:)

Comment: @HansPassant : I'm not using the ReportProgress,this is sample of please check the updated question

Comment: Consulting my crystal ball, it says: "he's using the Excel Application class in his background worker.  Which is a single-threaded COM object, all calls run on the thread that created it.  Which is probably the UI thread so his UI still freezes".

Comment: @HansPassant :  so to solve this issue i must not use the COM object ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like COM issue. 
Probably you should try using [MTA, instead of STA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta)

Helpfull links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate.aspx