# Run IVMRWindowlessControl9.GetCurrentImage() in background

Tags: c#, wpf, video, directshow, directshow.net

I have a webcam control using DirectShow.NET. I've created a custom control to display video and capture an image from a webcam. I'm using that custom control in another WPF window. I have a function `public Bitmap CaptureImage()` in the custom control to abstract away a little bit of the DirectShow programming and simply return a `Bitmap`. Since the images are relatively large (1920x1080), the `GetCurrentImage()` function of the `IVMRWindowlessControl9` takes quite a while to process (2-3 seconds). I've stepped through my code and can confirm that this call is the only one that takes a long time to process.

Because of this, the GUI thread in my main WPF window hangs, causing it to be unresponsive for a few seconds, so if I want to display a progress spinner while the image is being captured, it will just remain frozen.

Here is the code for `CaptureImage()`:

```
public Bitmap CaptureImage()
{
  if (!IsCapturing)
    return null;

  this.mediaControl.Stop();
  IntPtr currentImage = IntPtr.Zero;
  Bitmap bmp = null;

  try
  {
    int hr = this.windowlessControl.GetCurrentImage(out currentImage);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    if (currentImage != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      BitmapInfoHeader bih = new BitmapInfoHeader();
      Marshal.PtrToStructure(currentImage, bih);

      ...
      // Irrelevant code removed 
      ...

      bmp = new Bitmap(bih.Width, bih.Height, stride, pixelFormat, new IntPtr(currentImage.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(bih)));
      bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to capture image:" + ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(currentImage);
  }

  return bmp;
}
```

In order to fix this, I've tried to run this as a background task as follows:

```
public async void CaptureImageAsync()
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      CaptureImage();
    });
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple ways to do this including using `BackgroundWorker`s, but it seems that any time I make this call asynchronously, it creates this error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'DirectShowLib.VideoMixingRenderer9'
>   to interface type 'DirectShowLib.IVMRWindowlessControl9'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{8F537D09-F85E-4414-B23B-502E54C79927}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The error always happens when on this line:

```
int hr = this.windowlessControl.GetCurrentImage(out currentImage);
```

Calling `CaptureImage()` synchronously yields normal results. The image is captured and everything works as intended. However, switching to using any kind of asynchronous functionality gives that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having two issues here. First of all the original slowliness of the API is behavior by design. MSDN [mentions this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390541) as:

> However, frequent calls to this method will degrade video playback performance.

Video memory might be pretty slow for read-backs - this is the 2-3 second processing problem, not the resolution of the image *per se*. Bad news is that it is highly likely that even polling snapshots from background thread is going to affect the visual stream.

This method was and is intended for taking sporadic snapshots, esp. those initiated by user interactively, not automated. Applications needing more intensive and automated, and those not affecting visual feed snapshots are supposed to intercept the feed before it is sent to video memory (there are options to do it, and most popular yet clumsy is use of Sample Grabber).

Second, you are likely to be hitting .NET threading issue [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18318885/868014), which triggers the mentioned exception. It is easy to use the same interface pointer in native code development by sneaky violating COM threading rules and passing the interface pointer between apartments. Since CLR is adding a middle layer between your code and COM object doing additional safety checks, you can no longer operate with the COM object/interfaces from background thread because COM threading rules are enforced.

I suppose you either have to keep suffering from long freezes associated with direct API calls, or add native code development that helps to bypass the freezes (especially, for example, a helper filter which captures frames before sending to video memory and in the same time implementing helper functionality for .NET caller to support background thread calls). Presumably you can also do all DirectShow related stuff in a pool of helper [MTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta) threads which solve you the background thread caller problem, but in this case you will most likely need to move this code from your UI thread which is STA - I don't think it something people often, if at all, doing.

Comment: Great explanation - could you expand a bit on the "and most popular yet clumsy is use of Sample Grabber" statement?  Why is the Sample Grabber way clumsy and what would be a better way?

Comment: @Roman R. Could you provide a little bit more detail on how to implement a pool of MTA threads for the DirectShow related code? I'm unable to open a WPF window in an MTA thread because it requires its thread to be STA. I've been trying to implement the methods you've mentioned but can't seem to come up with a working solution.

Comment: @MikeDinescu: I think this goes beyond the scope of this question, I made a note note to write on this some time later.

Comment: @AlanThomas: This problem has easy solution in native code domain, that is if you'd have native code parts you perhaps would not even run into these problems. With .NET you have to be accurate with COM threading, and your use of DirectShow pointers in UI STA thread basically leaves no options to use the same interface on a worker thread simultaneously. Besides trying to initialize UI thread as MTA (what you have tried), you could move your entire DirectShow logic to MTA (initialization etc.) which would give you the option to use interface on a concurrent MTA worker thread, I suppose.

Comment: I have no certainty this is going to be a good solution though. I myself always handled this in native code even when higher level code was managed. DirectShow graph and video renderer is basically fine to be in worker thread, even though I don't recommend it for other reasons. Overall I see not so much space for improvement here especially that as I said proper threading does not solve the other problem of reading back from video memory and its impact on performance.

Comment: I've worked on this issue on and off since I asked this question but still came to no solution. However, this has answered my original question so I'll mark it as accepted.