# Windows forms in a plugin

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a dll which is running as an out-of-process plugin in another application.

When the main application calls into my plugin my code runs in a thread-pool thread (I think) inside my plugins's appdomain. It is a MTA thread.

My question is **what is the correct way to show a messagebox/dialog in my plugin?**

Most answers I have found only says the dialog should open in "the GUI thread" but I don't have a GUI-thread in my appdomain! Tried searching for a definition of GUI-thread but could not find anything. Some hints says it is the thread where `Application.Run` is executed.

What I have tried is to just create a STA-thread and open the messagebox/dialog there. It seems to work most of the time but occationally I get a strange 100% CPU usage inside the `ShowDialog` method.

Should I start a message loop with `Application.Run` in my own appdomain? Should it run just during the callback or is it expensive to create/teardown so I should create it at start and have it running all the time?

(I have access to the main application's window handle which I use as parent/owner)

Comment: Doesn't the appliaction you're plugging into provide an API to show a dialog?

Comment: @CodeCaster, unfortunatly not.

Comment: I think `ShowDialog` is not your dll job. You can provide a message(function return value for example) which can be showed by calling application. Or create event which can be wired up by calling application

Comment: @adrianm I agree with Fabio above... even if you managed to invoke a method in the calling app, you are creating dependencies... perhaps you could put a wrapper around the main app and thereby effectively provide an API which permits dialogue interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Win API NativeMethods:

`/// Direct Task Dialog call.
[DllImport("comctl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "TaskDialog")]
public static extern int TaskDialog(IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hInstance,
            string pszWindowTitle, string pszMainInstruction, string pszContent,
            int dwCommonButtons, IntPtr pszIcon, out int pnButton);`

You can find good using example here:
https://code.google.com/p/cassini/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but don't understand how it answers the question. Which thread should I open the task dialog from? Standard thread pool MTA thread, my own created STA thread?

Comment: Use the STA model. See related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta

Comment: So you mean create a STA thread and open the Task Dialog there. That is what I do now but I open the normal message box instead. Why should Task Dialog work where MessageBox doesn't. (I have tried to call the native win32 message box with the same result)