# FolderBrowserDialog doesn't appear at all when running outside of ISE

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which should allow a user to pick a folder location for a specific file and then I will use that location to take action on the file.  However, when I run the script outside of the ISE the FolderBrowserDialog doesn't appear at all.  I have looked behind the powershell window and behind all other windows and it never appears.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$FolderBrowser.Description = "Description"
$FolderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
$FolderBrowser.RootFolder = 'MyDocuments' 
if($FolderBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq $true){
     Do some stuff
}
```

Any thoughts on why it might not show up?  Are there certain powershell settings that need to be turned on to have things appear from the console?

Comment: Not able to reproduce. What exactly do you mean with "outside of the ISE"?

Comment: In the ISE the dialog appears, but just opening powershell console to run the script it doesn't show up

Comment: Are you using PowerShell v2? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: If I paste the cod into an PoSh console (replacing 
`Do some stuff` with `"Showdialog True"`) it works without problem. With Powershell V5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this issue before in PS v2, here's how I have fixed it.

Save the code in a .ps1 file and run it like this:

```
powershell -STA -File "path/to/file.ps1"
```

ISE v2 runs in STA, and console v2 runs in MTA.

More information: [Could you explain STA and MTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta)

Comment: That was it.  I was on PS v2