# Sending messages to STA thread

Tags: c#, .net, com, sta, mta

I have read little bit about COM threading model: MTA and STA, for example this SO post:

[Difference between MTA and STA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta)

There we can read that to communicate with object within STA we need to *pump messages* to this apartament.

My question is how to do it (C#/VB.NET)? How can I *pump message* from another thread, so for example, text box in WinForms updates (chagnes its text or whatever)?

Any remarks/pointers are acceptable too.

Comment: You *could* use Application.DoEvents, but that can be trickier than it looks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/ the real question is why do you need to pump messages?

Comment: You misunderstood the post. It is the responsibility of the thread that joined STA to pump messages sent to its windows; if it doesn't, COM objects it hosts won't work. COM calls to STA objects from outside their apartment are implemented by sending window messages to a  special hidden window maintained by COM runtime; if the thread doesn't pump messages, those calls won't get delivered. You can't force the thread to pump messages from outside - it just something it does (or does not, in which case it's buggy). Now, is there a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Just pure curosity I guess. I just have been reading about platform invoke and COM interop and wanted to have full view of how things work.

Comment: [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/150777/info-descriptions-and-workings-of-ole-threading-models) is the best I know of on the subject. It doesn't describe interop though, just "classic" COM.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik, you could put your comments together in an answer, you helped a lot :)