# What is a COM threading appartment?

Tags: multithreading, object, com, pywin32, apartments

I registered a COM object with pywin32.

```
win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(TimeServer)
```

I understand an apartment is some conceptual framework of keeping the threads and objects together?

What is the point of apartments?

A quote from Mark Hammond's book on pywin32:

> Each object lives in what COM terms a threading apartment, of which
> there are two types, free-threaded and single-threaded. A process can
> have zero or one free-threaded apartments and any number of
> single-threaded apartments (one for each thread with a single-threaded
> object).

I am assuming the object refers to thing I registered. What about the threads, are they the applications calling initializing this objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could you explain STA and MTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta)

Comment: Apartments are just threads, plus another one for objects that support multithreading.

Comment: How does it connect to the COM object? Is the apartment the thread of the COM object?