# Get clipboard text in async method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy, clipboard

I have a problem copying text after the async method execution.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dawn-4s0jy5?file=/src/App.js

```
 import copyClipboard from 'copy-text-to-clipboard'

 const delayTime = (ms: number) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms))
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 const copyText1= `copy text 1`
 copyClipboard(copyText1)

 await delayTime(5000)

 const copyText2= `copy text 2`
 copyClipboard(copyText2)
```

I always return a "Copy Text 1"

I expected my copy is "Copy Text 2". What's the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use delayTime? can you share the problem in codesandbox?

Comment: I think the user needs to interact with the page first. When I run the code provided I don't get any text in the clipboard.

Comment: @Alopwer Thank you for your reply. I have to wait around 5 seconds to check another API's status. If the API returns true, I will copy `copy text 2`

Comment: @dacoten, anyway, it will be easier to say what's wrong if you share minimum reproducible example

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sure, I make a copy action from click on a Button. I make sure that CopyText1 is always returned. But after waiting for the SYNC function, I cannot copy from CopyText2. 
I have referred to another solution. But I don't understand because it is a C# solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362438/get-clipboard-text-in-async-method

Comment: @Alopwer: here we go. Please help me!
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dawn-4s0jy5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @dacoten, for me the code works as expected, it copies copy text 1 then waits for 5 seconds and copies copy text 2

Comment: @Alopwer in Firefox 104 only "copy text 1" is in the clipboard

Comment: `copy()` returns `false` for me the second time, so it fails to copy. It's a bit unfortunate that it doesn't give the reason as the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) would in the promise rejection. But the documentation of the `copy()` function does mention that is must be called in response to a user interaction, which isn't the case for the second one. There it is invoked by a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @dacoten, ok so it works 50/50, the function copy returns the boolean meaning if the text was copied, so for me it returns false sometimes, maybe it's the library issue

Comment: A solution for this will be to create a useEffect and a state for status, then when status changes just call copy function once again, and try to use native ClipboardApi instead of this library

Comment: @Ivar I wouldn't be surprised if the browser was blocking it as the user hasn't interacted with the page. When I click on the page during the test, both `copy()` return true.

Comment: @evolutionxbox For the initial one yes. But in the codesandbox OP provided, the initial copy works while the second one doesn't.